# Evaluate time lag between an event in exogenous variables, and the response of a endogenous variable in regression SARIMAX model

Tags: autoregressive, lags, intervention-analysis

I am currently using autoregressive models to assess the influence of exogenous variables on the dynamics of a shellfish population. These exogenous factors are water temperature, salinity, and food concentration in the aquatic environment. I opted for the regression SARIMAX model due to its capacity to provide beta coefficients, which enable me to gauge the significance of these external variables in forecasting the endogenous one.

At this point, I am keen on determining the time lag between alterations in the exogenous variables and their impact on the endogenous variable. Unfortunately, it appears that my current model may not facilitate this analysis.

Any suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated.